# Why does a strong reference to parent UIViewController in performBatchUpdates leak an activity?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview

I just finished debugging a very nasty `UIViewController` leak, such that the UIViewController was not dealloc'd even after calling `dismissViewControllerAnimated`.

I tracked down the issue to the following block of code:

```
    self.dataSource.doNotAllowUpdates = YES;

    [self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
        [self.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        self.dataSource.doNotAllowUpdates = NO;
    }];
```

Basically, if I make a call to [`performBatchUpdates`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621505-dismissviewcontrolleranimated?language=objc) and then immediately call [`dismissViewControllerAnimated`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621505-dismissviewcontrolleranimated?language=objc), the UIViewController gets leaked and the `dealloc` method of that `UIViewController` never gets called. The UIViewController hangs around forever.

Can someone explain this behavior? I assume `performBatchUpdates` runs over some time interval, say, 500 ms, so I would assume that after said interval, it would call these methods and then trigger the dealloc.

The fix appears to be this:

```
    self.dataSource.doNotAllowUpdates = YES;

    __weak __typeof(self)weakSelf = self;

    [self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
        __strong __typeof(weakSelf)strongSelf = weakSelf;

        if (strongSelf) {
            [strongSelf.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]];
        }
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        __strong __typeof(weakSelf)strongSelf = weakSelf;

        if (strongSelf) {
            strongSelf.dataSource.doNotAllowUpdates = NO;
        }
    }];
```

Note that the `BOOL` member variable, `doNotAllowUpdates`, is a variable I added that prevents any kind of dataSource / collectionView updates while a call to performBatchUpdates is running.

I searched around for discussion online about whether or not we should use the weakSelf/strongSelf pattern in `performBatchUpdates`, but did not find anything specifically on this question.

I am happy that I was able to get to the bottom of this bug, but I would love a smarter iOS developer to explain to me this behavior I am seeing.

Comment: It'd be interesting to see if you could work out if it was the updates block or the completion block that was causing the retain cycle. As you say neither should permanently hold on to their block - I can only assume that when the collection view is removed from its superview it stops running any batched updates and doesn't call or release the completion block. Worth a radar in my opinion.

Comment: @jrturton Ahh this seems like the most likely explanation! I'll see if I can repro this in the debugger based on this insight.

Comment: @jrturton alas unable to repro in debugger...it does seem like both blocks, at least, are always called. Maybe the internals are not nil'ing the blocks though if dismiss is called in the middle?

Comment: I'd file a radar. There shouldn't be a retain cycle created here, as you say in the comments to the answer - single-shot blocks like this should be cleared once they're executed.

Comment: @jrturton ok will do. If you answer this question I will accept it, for the bonus 50 points, b/c I think that is the best explanation of what I have seen.

Comment: I don't think I deserve the bounty, but I'll not say no ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As you figured out, when `weak` is not used a retain cycle is created.

The retain cycle is caused by `self` having a strong reference to `collectionView` and `collectionView` now has a strong reference to `self`.

One must always assume that `self` could have been deallocated before an asynchronous block is executed. To handle this safely two things must be done:

1. Always use a weak reference to `self` (or the ivar itself)
2. Always confirm `weakSelf` exists before passing it as a `nunnull`
   param

**UPDATE:**

Putting a little bit of logging around `performBatchUpdates` confirms a lot:

```
- (void)logPerformBatchUpdates {
    [self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
        NSLog(@"starting reload");
        [self.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:[self.collectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems]];
        NSLog(@"finishing reload");
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        NSLog(@"completed");
    }];

    NSLog(@"exiting");
}
```

prints:

```
starting reload
finishing reload
exiting
completed
```

This shows that the completion block is fired AFTER leaving the current scope, which means it is dispatched asynchronously back to the main thread.

You mention that you immediately dismiss the view controller after doing the batch update. I think this is the root of your issue:

After some testing, the only way I was able recreate the memory leak was by dispatching the work before dismissing. It's a long shot, but does your code look like this by chance?:

```
- (void)breakIt {
    // dispatch causes the view controller to get dismissed before the enclosed block is executed
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
            [self.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:[self.collectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems]];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            NSLog(@"completed: %@", self);
        }];
    });
    [self.presentationController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

The code above leads to `dealloc` not being called on the view controller.

If you take your existing code and simply dispatch (or performSelector:after:) the `dismissViewController` call you will likely fix the issue as well.

Comment: You are correct on all fronts, however, as you can see from my code snippet above, even with the strong reference to self, it should be cleaned up after the completion block is run and the retain cycle is released. It is not clear to me how a retain cycle is created and the UIViewController is never de-alloced give my specific code snippet above.

Comment: the retain cycle should be quite clear. self retains the collection view and the collection view now retains self. one of these pointers needs to be weak to prevent the retain cycle (hence making `weakSelf`). i'm not sure what cleanup you are referring to since UICollectionView is a black box... i would NOT expect collectionView to nil out it's completion block and you definitely shouldn't rely on it

Comment: Let's complete your logic: assume UICollectionView does not nil out its completion block. UICollectionView starts to perform batch updates, invoking the first (strongly retained) block. UIViewController is dismissed, but cannot clean up because the second completion block has a strong reference. 100 ms go by for animation effects. UICollectionView invokes its completion block. Now, all blocks are run, references to said blocks should be cleaned up/nil'd etc, and UIViewController has no more refs and can dealloc. This should simply delay, not prevent, dealloc'ing. Right?

Comment: Moreover -- I cannot find any examples of performBatchUpdates on the internet that uses this weak reference pattern. Why aren't all apps leaking UIViewControllers like crazy and crashing, if the retain cycle created by performBatchUpdates is never broken even after it has run?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a bug with UICollectionView. API users should not expect single-run block parameters to be retained beyond the execution of the task, so preventing reference cycles should not be an issue.

UICollectionView should be clearing up any references to blocks once it has finished the batch update process, or if the batch update process is interrupted (for example, by the collection view being removed from the screen).

You've seen for yourself that the completion block is called even if the collection view is taken off-screen during the update process, so the collection view should then be nilling out any reference it has to that completion block - it will never be called again, regardless of the current state of the collection view.